# What might cause a high $\chi^2$ value of likelihood ratio criterion, even though transformed plot looks very similar to the original?

Tags: statistical-significance, maximum-likelihood, chi-squared-test, data-transformation

[image: Azimuthal angle distributio]

The label with "_norm" is the azimuthal angle $\phi$ distribution of the parameter, after Yeo Johnson transformation.

I have been calculating the likelihood coefficient using $\chi^2 = 2( logL(\hat{\lambda}) - logL(\lambda_o))$, where $\hat{\lambda}$ is the value that denotes the maximized likelihood profile and $\lambda_o=1$, for each of the 4 plots with changed parameter SigyFactor.

Even though the plots look very similar before and after Yeo Johnson, the $\chi^2$ values for likelihood ratio criterion were ~ 10, 13, 5 and 4 respectively. 
I assume, these values are above 5% critical value, 3.64 for one d.o.f. in this case.

Comment: Large sample size means you can pick up trivial deviations from the null. There's a *host* of questions already on site that address this issue in various specific situations (I'd guess well over a hundred). If rejecting a small effect size with a large sample seems like a bad idea, that kind of point-null hypothesis test was likely never the right tool in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion